# Calling function from outside the class with existing class member pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, smart-pointers

Im stuck with an issue connected to smart pointers. I have a class **Property** which inherits from class **Cell** and I want to pass current class member pointer to **Player** class member function.

```
class Player {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cell>> cells;
    int money;
public:
    
    bool buysProperty(std::shared_ptr<Cell> property)
    {
         //some code in which i would like to call both Cell and Property functions
    }    
};
```

And that's how I call this function from inside of Property class:

```
class Property : public Cell {
private:

public:
    void action(Player* currentPlayer) {
        currentPlayer->buysProperty(std::make_shared<Property>(this)) {
        }
    }
};
```

After compilation i get this error:
*'Property::Property(const Property &)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const Property &'*

I don't know what's wrong, am I calling the function wrong, or is that an issue with the function body?
Maybe it's the 'this' keyword issue?
Thank you for all your time and answers :)

Comment: *Where* do you get this error? Please try to create a [mre] to show us, and add a comment in that code where you get the error. And is the single line you show as error really the only output you get in your full build log?

Comment: Note that even in the best of times, `std::make_shared<Property>(this)` would make a shared pointer referring to a **copy** of `this`. Maybe look into `std::enable_shared_from_this` and its `shared_from_this` member function.

Comment: Is `*this` owned by another `shared_ptr`? Or, was it created by `new`?

Comment: **Someprogrammerdude** Yes, only one line, only one error. Happens in built-in file called xutility line 138.
**Botje** Do you mean that I need to create copy constructor and try to work on it? I will read about std::enable_shared_from_this.
**DanielLangr** In other class called Game I have std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cell>> and append Property class members by using constructor. I believe that's where '*this' is?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this It has some boundary conditions for it to work for example you must make all instances of Player (and its derived classes) with std::make_shared, shared_from_this() only works if the class already has a valid share_ptr pointing to it (also make sure you derive public from enable_shared_from_this!)

Comment: It looks like a design flow: circular dependency, need to call specialized interface, etc. You should decide which class should have the ownership, I would say "Player has collection of ptrs to Cells". If Cell needs a ptr to Player, use `weak_ptr`. Then, make a Cell interface (virtual method) that can be called from Player and provide correct Property implementation.

Comment: `std::make_shared` creates a new object, and forwards the arguments to the appropriate constructor. It doesn't take an existing pointer and turn it into a "shared pointer". (The "smart pointers" are misnamed; they are almost nothing like pointers at all.)